# Is it possible to invite someone to chat?

Tags: support, chat

Sometimes discussions erupt in the comments. Now, this is not a forum. I see those are moved to the chat sometimes by moderators, but how do I actually pro-actively start a chat with someone when I see I get into a discussion that shouldn't really be in the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some help in the help.

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms

Basically you just create a chat room and add another comment inviting that user to the chat room and hope they accept.

It's not the same as the mod cleanup and move commands, but it gets the job done, if you want to get rid of the comments, just flag them.

At the very least, doing this will show us mods who the chatty fellow is and who is playing by the rules.

Comment: I don't know if I've said this here or just elsewhere on SE, but... SE *really* ought to just allow any user (or at least, with fairly modest rep) to invoke "let's continue this in chat" (probably without the mod effect of deleting existing comments). For one, importing the *context* is helpful, and having to jump through multiple hoops to do the "polite" thing disincentivizes doing so. This is especially aggravating when enough back-and-forth *will* cause the option to pop up for anyone. The current situation is just needless barriers.

Comment: I agree with Matthew.